# Selenium Server - Pre-define constant for the app being tested?

Tags: php, cakephp, testing, selenium

Using the Selenium Server, is there a way to define a constant for the app being tested through Selenium? To be more specific, I'm working with an app built on CakePHP. I would like to have Selenium define a PHP constant for the app to use before the app runs such that this constant will only be defined when the app is being run through Selenium. Is there a way something like this could be achieved? Thank you much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just checking to see if the Selenium Server was running from within my program. To do this, I checked if the port the server runs on was open. I did this using the following code:

```
if(!defined('SELENIUM_TEST')){
    $fp = @fsockopen('localhost', 4444);
    if ($fp !== false) {
        define('SELENIUM_TEST', true);
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

As long as this is done before you need to check the constant, then it should work fine.

WARNING: If the Selenium Server is not running this will cause the app to stall while attempting to contact the socket.

Answer (score 0):

If you use phpunit http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/selenium.html to execute your selenium tests, then you can define a constant in the setUp()-method. Then this constant is set for every test.

Comment: Actually, I'm already running my Selenium tests through PHPUnit. Unfortunately, this is where I'm having the problem. I want a constant to be defined which tells the app to use a different database. Using this method, any functions called from the unit test directly do indeed have the constant defined and use the other database. However, when Selenium opens the browser which the unit test runs on, that instance of the app in the browser does not have this constant defined and uses the regular database. Any suggestions on how I might fix that? Thanks.